# Is there a recommended way to typeset fractions (in brackets) in a sentence?

Tags: fractions

In these two cases the inner brackets are added to avoid ambiguity. I was wondering if there is an alternative to dropping the outer brackets altogether?

`...some quantity defined by a quotient ($y / (\Delta y)$) in this case...`

`...some fractional value (e.g. $z = 1 / (2 x)$)...`

Comment: For one, you would want `$z = 1 / (2 x)$` instead of `z = $1 / (2 x)$`, or else the spacing around the `=` will not be proper.

Comment: The outer pairs of parentheses are there because they enclose what are called "parenthetic remarks". In the first case, the material in parentheses illustrates the term "quotient"; in the secon, the parenthetic remark illustrates the term "fractional value". If you can't stand the use of parentheses in these cases, consider using pairs of commas or pairs of em-dashes, or simply avoid making parenthetic remarks in the first place. My guess is that if you find that you need to make parenthetic remarks from time to time, you'll also find that using parentheses in such cases is quite natural.

Comment: You could actual brackets [ ] or  \lbrack and \rbrack for the inner pair.   In math mode one uses size differentiation, but here the outer pair are not math symbols.

Comment: I would try to avoid this at all because the slash is not quite common when typesetting mathematical stuff. In display math mode you could use `\frac{}{}` instead. On the other hand, this might put too much emphasis on a small example. An alternative might be to place such examples in the margin column using a "real" fraction again.

Comment: The TeXbook suggests using `\big(` and `\big)` for the outer parentheses (this also works for text-mode parentheses).

Comment: parentheses are not needed around either `2 x` or `\Delta y` because there is no ambiguity about what is meant.  (you *would* need parentheses if the expressions were `2 + x` or `\Delta + y`.)  you might find some hints in this publication helpful: [mathematics into type](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/mit-2.pdf).

Comment: @Matthias - Since the OP wrote in the title that the math expressions occur "in a sentence", it may not be all that helpful to write "In display math mode you could...".

Comment: @Mico I do not agree. It is common practise in scientific publications to use display math style within a sentence. This should be taken into consideration if the formula is "large enough". Having a fraction involved, embedding a formula using the inline style tends to be ugly and hard to read. The OP explictitly asked for alternatives, so this one should be mentioned.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your comment applies to `\Delta y` because this is an undivideable symbol. `1 / 2 x`, however, means `1 / 2 \cdot x`, which is not equal to `1 / (2 x)`.

Comment: @Matthias -- i'm afraid my mathematics skills are not sufficient to discern the difference between `2x` and `2\cdot x`; if the `\cdot` were actually present in the expression, then there would be no question of removing the parentheses.

Comment: @Matthias - I think you misread what I wrote; so sorry that I evidently wasn't clear enough. I continue to fail to understand how making recommendations for typesetting a fractional expression in display-math mode helps the OP solve his/her stated objective of writing fractional terms, such as `1/(2x)` and  `y/\Delta y`, "in a sentence".

Comment: @Mico Maybe I misunderstood the question of the OP. A *sentence* can easily span multiple lines and even display math material. Do you think that the OP means a single *line?* If this was the case, I would remove the 5th option from my answer.

Comment: @Matthias - (I was holding off answering your question for a while, in the hope that the OP would jump in and clarify his/her objectives. This didn't pan out, did it?) I interpreted the expression "to typeset fractions ... in a sentence" as implying that the OP was (mostly? exclusively?) interested in finding out to how to typeset fractional expressions in inline math mode. However, that may not, in fact, have been the OP's (sole) aim.

Comment: Thank you @Steven, I've moved the $ to the correct position. Thank you @Mico, @John and @Bruno, I tried square brackets but they didn't look any better than the double parentheses so I moved the outer parentheses in my first example inside the $$ and tried `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` and it looks quite satisfactory. @barbara I think the pdf you provided will be useful. @Matthias thank you for the different versions. I like the negative exponent for my second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{Original version}
\par\emph{Slightly modified.}
\par\dots{} some quantity defined by a quotient ($y / \Delta y$) in this case \dots
\par\dots{} some fractional value (e.\,g., $z = 1 / (2\,x)$) \dots

\section{Replacing the outer pair of parentheses}
\par\emph{Might be a good option.}
\par\dots{} some quantity defined by \emph{the} quotient $y / \Delta y$ in this case \dots
\par\dots{} some fractional value, e.\,g., $z = 1 / (2\,x)$, \dots

\section{Using a negative exponent}
\par\emph{Seems even better.}
\par\dots{} some quantity defined by a quotient ($y \cdot \Delta y^{-1})$ in this case \dots
\par\dots{} some fractional value (e.\,g., $z = (2\,x)^{-1}$), \dots

\section{Using a text fraction}
\par\emph{Not recommended because it increases the line spread.}
\par\dots{} some quantity defined by a quotient \big($\tfrac{y}{\Delta y}$\big) in this case \dots
\par\dots{} some fractional value \big(e.\,g., $z = \tfrac{1}{2\,x}$\big), \dots

\section{Using display math style}
\par\emph{May put too much emphasis on the formulae to be embedded.}
\par\dots{} some quantity defined by a quotient 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{y}{\Delta y}
\end{equation*}
in this case \dots
\par\dots{} some fractional value, e.\,g., 
\begin{equation*}
z = \frac{1}{2\,x}\,, 
\end{equation*}
\dots

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the MWE]